# Limit of discrete series representation $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have a couple of elementary question about the limit of discrete series representation (=LDS) of $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$. I find the topic fairly confusing.

Write $I(\mu_1, \mu_2, s)$ the prinicpal series and $M :I(\mu_1, \mu_2, s) \rightarrow  I(\mu_1, \mu_2, -s)$ for the intertwiner. Here $\mu_j$ is either the trivial character or the sign character of $\mathbb{R}^\times$.

1. The reps $I(sign, 1,0)$ and $I(1, sign,0)$ are the LDS?
2. Is the LDS a proper subquotient?
3. Is the LDS stable under character twist by $sign \circ \det$?
4. What does the intertwiner $M:I(sign, 1,0) \rightarrow  I(1, sign,0)$ do?
5. Why do we call it LDS, when it is simply a discrete series representation?
6. Is there a good reference for this topic simply for $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited, in response to questioner's follow-up: In general, limits of discrete series are not *whole* principal series, but subquotients. But in the present example, it is possible to get the impression that the "odd/ramified" principal series $s=0$ (with intertwining $s\rightarrow -s$ normalization) is the "limit of discrete series", since, unlike the *unramified* principal series, there are no "lower" $K$-types to be obviously left out.

It may be somewhat simpler to look at $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ rather than $GL(2)$, since the former has a unique "odd" principal series for given complex parameter $s$, while $GL(2)$ has three. In any case, the diagonal $-1,1$ element in $GL(2)$ is not so much the distinguisher of "odd" principal series.

Rather, the odd/even business is already visible in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ in the diagonal $\pm 1_2$ lying in the intersection $P\cap K$ of the standard (upper-triangular) parabolic and the standard maximal compact $SO(2)=SO(2,\mathbb R)$. That is, the odd principal series induce the character
$\pmatrix{a & * \cr 0 & a^{-1}}\rightarrow |a|^{2s-1}\cdot \hbox{sgn}(a)$.

The terminology is inherited because, at the Lie algebra level, and in some models, the LDS is indeed "the same as" a genuine discrete series. However, its (matrix) coefficient functions are not in $L^2(G)$, so it doesn't qualify on *that* account.

I think Lang's old book on $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ talks about such details. Gelfand-Graev-PiatetskiShapiro's book on automorphic functions does, and usefully juxtaposes the p-adic analogues of things. I'd think Knapp's "Repn ... by example" would do these examples. Varadarajan's small gray volume "Harmonic analysis on ... (semi-simple? reductive?) groups" emphasizes such things, and gives computational details.

The sort of computation necessary to understand the intertwiners directly is also illustrated, although in the *even* principal series case, in some notes of mine: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/ios.pdf  Similar devices will succeed for odd principal series.

Edit: specifically in response to the questioner's follow-up, directly computing the effect of natural intertwining operators for $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, I seem to find that at $s=0$ (in the questioner's normalization, so the functional equation is $s\rightarrow -s$) the "positive" $K$-types are the kernel, and the "negative" $K$-types are the image. So the "limit of discrete series" seems *not* to be the whole principal series.

But this leaves something to be done when we return to $GL(2,\mathbb R)$: specifically, the element $\varepsilon=\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1}$ interchanges the non-zero $\pm$ $SO(2)$-types. If we too-glibly presume that the repn space for the $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ principal series is the same as that for $GL(2,\mathbb R)$, this seems to say that the $s=0$ odd/ramified principal series is irreducible, since the positive and negative $K$-types are now bound to each other.

Yet the direct computation of intertwinings (which are also $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ integertwinings, given by the same integrals!) say there *is* a kernel, and that the image is proper. How to reconcile this?

The only possibility is that the multiplicities of the $SO(2)$-types in the ramified $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ principal series are not $1$, but are $2$. (Here I'm thinking of the odd principal series that maps to itself under the intertwining. I've not thought through the analogous issues for the other two ramified principal series for $GL(2,\mathbb R)$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what puzzles me mostly, is how it can be a proper subrepresentation if the restriction to $O(2)$ are the same as for the ramified principal series representation. No $K$-type is substracted.

Comment: I see your point: for SL(2), "half" the K-types appear, and for GL(2), the diag(-1,1) (does it?) puts the two pieces together, so the "full" LDS has all the K-types of the whole (odd/ramified) principal series. Now I am a bit interested to do the computation of the intertwinings, because I _suspect_ that the self-intertwinings in the odd/ramified case have kernel(s) consisting of "half" the K-types. This should be ascertainable in finite time.

Comment: I supsect this because missing $K$-types would allow the construction of pseudo coefficients for the LDS, and allow trace formulas for weight one forms. Theorem 11.15 in Knightly, Li - "traces of Hecke operators" page 164 together with  the list on page 186  gives the result: No K type is missing. But they argue with the Lie algebra, so I do not see what the intertwiner is doing. In Bump "automorphic reps", the intertwiner is computed on the level of $O(2)$ types. My whole problem is how to interpret all this information, and what is so special about the LDS to not to call it PS.

Comment: To reiterate some of what I added to the "answer": this is a situation in which the "slight" differences between the categories of repns matter much more than usual. My sketch indicates that, _whichever_ category we're in, the LDS is _not_ the whole principal series. Also, again, there is the non-$L^2$-ness of matrix coefficient functions.